# Refactoring: Move Xtend class to another package

Tags: eclipse, refactoring, xtend

**Does the latest eclipse plugin for Xtend support moving classes from one package to another (and automatically update reference to the class)?**

Using eclipse Mars, I try to the following:

1. Right click file `Test.xtend` which contains `class Test {}`
2. Select Refactor / Move ...
3. Move `Test.xtend` into a new package.

Result:

- The package name in the class `Test.xtend` is **not** changed to the new package.
- References to the class in other Xtend and Java classes are **not** updated.

Comment: and what question? Also see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=442287 if it's not similar your case, create new bug

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Alright, I found an existing bug see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the answer to my questions is: **no**.

Updates on this should hopefully come soon for the bug reported on it:

[Bug 421032
[xtend][refactoring] implement move refactoring for types](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=421032)